# functions in another js files are not called when the call is in for loop

Tags: node.js, for-loop, protractor

I have some functions in another js file "Login.js" when I call those function with in a for loop they are not executing. If I call without the loop its working fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated. the below script from my specs.js

```
it('and Login to MSIX', function () {
 var workbook = new excelData.Workbook();
    var converted;
    var data = [];
    workbook.xlsx.readFile('./tests/e2e/TestData/Testcase_data_v1.xlsx').then(function () {
var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Reports');
browser.waitForAngular();
    for (i = 2; i <= 4; i++) {
      for (j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
          var cellvalue = worksheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).value;
          var converted = JSON.stringify(cellvalue);
          data.push(converted);
      }
      username = data[0];
      password = data[1];
      userType =  data[2];

    });
    browser.waitForAngular();
    // call login scripts
    login.fillUsername(username);
    login.fillPassword(password);
    login.clickSignup();
    browser.waitForAngular();
    login.clickPrivacy();
    browser.waitForAngular();
    console.log("User " + username + " with user type "+userType+" logged in successfully");
    data = [];
  };
  });
});
```

Comment: can you add the code that works please ?

Comment: @taki, when I say without the loop that mean there won't be reading data from excel. like no code from `var workbook = new excelData.Workbook();    to   login.fillUsername(username);`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got this working with below code.

```
var excelData = require('exceljs');

module.exports = function() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var workbook = new excelData.Workbook();
        var converted;
        var data = [];
        workbook.xlsx.readFile('./tests/e2e/TestData/Testcase_data_v1.xlsx').then(function () {
            var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Reports');
            var rowno = worksheet.rowCount;
            var colno = worksheet.columnCount;
            console.log(rowno, colno);
            for (var i = 2; i <= 4; i++) {
                for (var j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
                    var cellvalue = worksheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).value;
                    data.push(cellvalue);
                }
            }
            return resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

in specs.js i did as below

```
var exRead = require('./readExcel');

describe('MSIX Smoke', function () {
  var userList = [];

  beforeAll(function(done) {

    browser.get('url');  //Dev url
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('title');
    exRead().then(function(excelData) {
      userList = prepData(excelData);
      done();
    });

  });
```